# Java JSON data without key value

Tags: java, json

This is problematic JSON data that I'm trying to read:

```
"555":{
    "ID":115,
    "name":"John Smith",
    "email":"john@gmail.com",
    "tel":"0123456789"
},
"568":{
    "ID":221,
    "name":"Xxxx xxxxx",
    "email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
    "tel":"0123456789"
}}
```

I want to read id, name and email and separate them with "\t", but I don't know key value because it is generated via random function.

```
String data;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); / sb is StringBuffer
String[] keyValues = JSONObject.getNames(json);
for(int i=0; keyValues.length < i; i++) {
   data = jsonObj.getString(keyValues[i]);
}
```

I encountered a few JSON Java examples here, but nothing like this. Can someone explain to me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JSON supports objects as children of objects. The `getJSONObject()` method is useful to retrieve those child objects

```
for(int i=0; keyValues.length < i; i++) {
  JSONObject obj = jsonObj.getJSONObject(keyValues[i]);
  System.out.println (obj.getInt("ID")+" "+obj.getString("name");
}
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)